# How can I query 1=1 or 1=0 in mongo?

Tags: mongodb

In SQL, it's possible to add a 1=1 or 1=0 query condition to essentially return all or no records, respectively.  How can I do the same in mongo?

Comment: To get all results you can use an empty object as the query `{}`. To get no results you could probably use `{_id: 0}` or something like that. Not guaranteed to return no results but likely.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking something like `{_id: null}`, same idea.  I'll just do that then, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As answered in the comments, the equivalence of a `1=1` query condition in mongo is to use the empty object `{}` as the query. For example, `db.foos.find({})`.

A `1=0` query condition can be simulated in mongo by passing an empty array to the `$in` query condition. For example, `db.foos.find({ _id: { $in: [] } })`. Additionally, using a javascript function that always returns false in a `$where` query condition works as well. For example, `db.foos.find({ $where: function() { return false } })`.

The added benefit of these two conditions for `1=0` compared to `{ _id: 0 }` or `{ _id: null }` is that it will work even if `0` or `null` are valid values for `_id` in your collection. However, I am not sure if either of these queries may carry additional performance penalties.

Answer (score 4):

Nowadays (as of version 3.6) you can express this directly:

```
{ $expr: { $eq: [1, 1] } }
```

or

```
{ $expr: { $eq: [0, 1] } }
```

Comment: Even simpler: `{ $expr: true }` or `{ $expr: false }` (tested with version 4)