# How to make a mongoose find query return null instead of throwing a CastError when the types are incompatible?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

## Problem

When using mongoose to find documents by a specific field, if the type of the field is different from the type of the queried value, then mongoose will attempt to cast the query value to the same type as the field.

However, if the value cannot be casted, then mongoose will throw a `CastError`.

This behavior can be seen in the following example, where mongoose will attempt to cast the string `'invalid object id'` to an `ObjectId` when trying to query for `Foo` documents by the `bar` field:

```
const fooSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  bar: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  }
});
const Foo = <any>mongoose.model<any>('Foo', fooSchema);
await Foo.findOne({ bar: 'invalid object id' });
```

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection
>   (rejection id: 1): CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value
>   "invalid object id" at path "bar" for model "Foo"

*(Similar error would occur if `bar` was some other types, such as `Number` or `Boolean` as well.)*

However, I don't like this behaviour. I very much prefer that the returned document simply becomes `null`, without an error being thrown. After all, if the value in the query cannot be casted, then the document logically also cannot exist under the given query.

Now, I am aware that I can simply do a check before constructing the query to ensure that I don't pass in a type that can't be casted. However, I don't like this approach because it results in having to duplicate code. Quite often, the code to handle what happens when the type is invalid will be exactly the same as the code to handle what happens if the document does not exist.

Additionally, I don't want to disable type checking completely either. So changing the type of the field to `Mixed` would not be a solution, as I would like the type check to still be there when I am creating a new document.

## Attempted Solutions

So I attempted to solve this issue by creating custom [query helpers](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#query-helpers) to check the type, and return null if it is invalid, or perform the query if it is valid.

```
fooSchema.query.byBar = function(id) {
  if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)) {
    return null;
  }

  return this.where('bar').equals(id);
};
```

Which I can then use with `Foo.findOne().byBar('invalid object id')`.

The problem with this solution however, is that it is no longer chainable. This means that if I were to try something such as `Foo.findOne().byBar('invalid object id').lean()`, it will throw an error if the type check fails (but will work fine when it passes the type check):

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection
>   (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'lean' of null

Trying to use static methods instead will run into the same problem.

```
fooSchema.statics.findOneByBar = function(id: any) {
  if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)) {
    return null;
  }

  return this.findOne({ bar: id });
};
```

## Question

So essentially, I want to be able to have the query return `null` if the type check fails, but still be chainable. I want the query to be chainable because I still want to be able to specify additional query conditions in the cases where the type is valid.

Now, if my attempted solution is on the right track, then what I need to do is instead of returning `null` directly if the type check fails, I return something from the chainable query builder api that will result in the query's final result to be `null`. I essentially need some sort of [`1=0` query condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32359076/how-can-i-query-1-1-or-1-0-in-mongo) (however, the linked question did not propose a guaranteed answer for the `1=0` condition). So my question is, **if my attempted solution is on the right track, then what do I return that is a chainable mongoose Query, but will cause the query to always result in `null` when the query is executed?**

Or alternatively, **if my attempted solution is on the wrong track, is there another way to make a mongoose find query result in `null` instead of throwing a `CastError` when the types are incompatible?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building off of the attempted solutions, I found two query conditions that seem to be functionally equivalent to `1=0`.

**1. Passing an empty array to the `$in` query condition.**

```
fooSchema.query.byBar = function(id) {
  if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)) {
    return this.where('bar').in([]);
  }

  return this.where('bar').equals(id);
};
```

**2. Using `$where` query condition that returns `false`.**

```
fooSchema.query.byBar = function(id) {
  if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)) {
    return this.$where('false');
  }

  return this.where('bar').equals(id);
};
```

The advantages of these two solutions is that they work regardless of the type of `bar` and the possible values it may contain, as long as the type check is done correctly. That means we don't need to have prior knowledge of what values may or may not be stored in the fields, so arbitrary numbers and booleans are supported by these solutions as well.

The disadvantage of these two solutions is that such a query helper needs to be added for every field where we need to return `null` if the types don't match, and it needs to be repeated for every model. So we do not have the flexibility of the original mongoose query builder api anymore, as well as resulting in a lot of duplicate code.

Additionally, I'm not sure if either of these two conditions carry performance penalties.

If the flexibility of the mongoose query builder api is needed, a work around could be to use a try-catch statement, as it will catch the `CastError` that is thrown. Though it is a bit cumbersome to write.

```
let foo;
try {
  foo = await Foo.findOne().where('bar').equals('invalid object id');
} catch (err) {
  foo = null;
}
```

Though, if anyone have an even better solution, I am interested in hearing it.

Answer (score 2):

May be my answer is a bit silly and straight forward. But I would like to do it this way.

```
fooSchema.statics.findOneByBar = function(id: any) {
  if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)) {
    id = "111111111111111111111111"; // other values are also possible
  }

  return this.findOne({ bar: id });
};
```

This is a valid `objectId` and it may never be generated by Mongodb ever. So this way the query will be valid and all the chainable functionality will be intact. Let me know if it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for answering, this does solve the problem posed in the example. However, I'm not sure if this solution would still work if the field type was something like `Number` or `Boolean`. Because in those cases, the field isn't restricted to a subset of all possible values. So I'm not sure if there exists anything that could cast to those types in the `findOne` query, but is still guaranteed to not match any existing documents. Please let me know if you know of any such values, since I am hoping for a solution that could be generalized.